# Streaming content to Vizio TV over DLNA

Tags: tv, hdtv, dlna

I have a 55" Vizio TV. I noticed in the on screen menus that it could stream content from my PC. I even managed to browse the video files on the PC. 
However, my MP4 files won't play on the TV.

What file format are supported, and what tool can convert to these formats (and what settings are needed if any).

Comment: will need more specific information about your tv, like the model number

Answer (score 1):

The [KooRaRoo](http://www.kooraroo.com/) DLNA server [is said](https://thebitplague.wordpress.com/2012/10/22/play-stream-video-from-pc-to-vizio-tv/comment-page-1/#comment-142) to work with Vizio TVs. It creates DivX, AVI, or MPEG video depending on your TV.

[Another comment](https://thebitplague.wordpress.com/2012/10/22/play-stream-video-from-pc-to-vizio-tv/comment-page-1/#comment-171) says Xvid AVI files work on his Vizio TV.

Free DLNA servers include [TVersity](http://tversity.com/) and [MediaTomb](http://mediatomb.cc/), which should also be able to output the required format.